# Query with parameter with golang and sqlserver driver

Tags: sql, sql-server, rest, go

I'm trying to get a specific item by ID from my sql server database. Here's my code :

```
var(
    allArticlesQry string = "SELECT * FROM Articles"
    findArticlesQry string = "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Id = ?1"
)

func FindArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    var id = vars["id"]
    var article Article

    db := connect()
    defer db.Close()

    stmt, err := db.Prepare(findArticlesQry)    
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    err = stmt.QueryRow(id).Scan(&article.Title, &article.Description, &article.Body, &article.Id)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(u.HttpResp{Status: 200, Body: article})
}
```

I'm using [this package](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb) for the sqlserver driver and it has this example who should work fine : `db.Query("SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = ?3, b = ?2, c = ?1", "x", "y", "z")`

But everytime I try to call this function it fails and returns : 
`2017/09/01 16:31:01 mssql: Incorrect syntax near '?'.`

So I don't really understand why my query doesn't work..

**EDIT**

I tried another way, I removed the part where I prepare the query before executing and now it doesn't crash my server, I have a response but the problem is still the same :

```
var row = db.QueryRow(findArticlesQry, id).Scan(&article.Title, &article.Description, &article.Body, &article.Id)
```

And the response :

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "description": "",
    "body": {
        "Number": 102,
        "State": 1,
        "Class": 15,
        "Message": "Incorrect syntax near '?'.",
        "ServerName": "DESKTOP-DLROBC4\\LOCALHOST",
        "ProcName": "",
        "LineNo": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `mssql` driver and not `sqlserver`?  Both are in that package but the latter expects parameters in a different format.

Comment: I'm using sqlserver driver, I'm not on my computer right now so I'll try in a couple hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per your comment, you are using the `sqlserver` driver, not the `mssql` driver, so you are using the wrong parameter format.  Per the documentation:

> The sqlserver driver uses normal MS SQL Server syntax and expects
>   parameters in the sql query to be in the form of either `@Name` or `@p1`
>   to `@pN` (ordinal position).
>
> `db.QueryContext(ctx, "select * from t where ID = @ID;", sql.Named("ID", 6))`

You should therefore change your query to be:

```golang
var(
    allArticlesQry string = "SELECT * FROM Articles"
    findArticlesQry string = "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Id = @p1"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I never mentioned the mssql driver btw, I mentioned sqlserver driver explicitly in my question actually, but thanks ! I'll try it when I'll have access to my computer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem with the placeholders. Why not try just ? for your placeholders as you're not shifting the order or repeating them. So try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Id = ?"
```

Comment: Still the same error, it's definitly a problem with the placeholder but I can't find any documentation on this since it's a community based package and not actively developed i think...

Comment: It looks like the driver claims it accepts the style you're trying to use for mssql but not sqlserver, perhaps check that too.

Comment: how do you pass the placeholder value?

Answer (score 1):

`db.Query("SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = ?3, b = ?2, c = ?1", "x", "y", "z")`, the question mark here works as placeholder, which later will be replaced with the value of 'x', 'y' and 'z' according to its order in the code during runtime.

But this:

`SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Id = ?1` is not a validate SQL statement, correct is to remove the question mark, or you could give a specific value to @Id, like:

`SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Id = @Id`

In a short word, `db.Query()` could build your query using placeholder, but your `findArticlesQry` variable is storing plain SQL statement, that should follow the basic SQL grammar, `?` is not allowed.